# Aligning three views in Android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have three views that are intended to look as follows:

```
+-----++-------------------------+
|  1  ||                         |
+-----+|           3             |
+-----+|                         |
|  2  ||                         |
+-----++-------------------------+
```

So far, so good. However...

Sometimes (3) is very small, and I want it centred in the vertical space used for (1) and (2).

```
+-----+
|  1  |+-------------------------+
+-----+|          3              |
+-----+|                         |
|  2  |+-------------------------+
+-----+
```

Other times, (3) is large, and I want (1) to align with the top (3), and for (2) to align with the bottom of (3):

```
+-----++-------------------------+
|  1  ||                         |
+-----+|                         |
       |           3             |
       |                         |
+-----+|                         |
|  2  ||                         |
+-----++-------------------------+
```

I have tried:

- an outer Relative layout: (1) and (2) overlap in the "small-3" case
- a linear layout containing (1) and (2) (with and without weights): the alignment at top/bottom does not work in the "big-3".
- an outer linear layout (with various height settings): I can not get case (2) and (3) to work with the same settings.

To give a little context, (1) and (2) are buttons and (3) is a text block of varying size.

At this point I assume I am missing some very basic setting (or widget) that will make this work as intended.

Note: I have not included source code because there have, literally, been over a dozen different configurations tried and none worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just asking the question helped...pretty sure the answer is to use ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Though, again, I can't seem to get the two button aligned top/bottom

Answer (score 0):

Use `ConstraintLayout` and use the `design` tab instead of writing the code yourself when using the `ConstraintLayout`, its pretty easy to achieve what you want. Dont use `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` for this.